# @Html.Partial return: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type __ but this dictionary requires a model item of type __

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, partial-views

I am trying to add a partial view to my MVC4 web application and I receive the following exception:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '...Meeting', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...UserProfile]'.

what I did so far:

1. i added to my controller this function:

> ```
> public PartialViewResult GetUsers()
>         {
>             var usersList = (from users in db.Users select users).ToList();
>             return PartialView(usersList);
>         }
> ```

1. I added the parital view:

> ```
> @model List<UserProfile>
> @{
>  <select id="Meeting_SetToUser" name="Meeting.SetToUser">
>         @foreach (var item in Model)
>         {
>             <option value="@item.UserId">@item.FirstName @item.LastName</option>
>         }
>     </select>
> }
> ```

1. i called the partialview from my view:

> ```
> @Html.Partial("GetUsers")
> ```

can you please direct me to were I am doing anything wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: my partialView type is List<UserProfile> I also inspected my controller's method and I am sending the same type to the partialView.

Comment: @Shlo, but where are you calling the `GetUsers` action?

Comment: I guess this way it is never called as you answered here... changing to Action solved the problem. next time I will try also a breakpoint and see if I reach the method or not. Thanks.

Comment: I mean the View which the PartialView belongs to. You never call your Action. With line `@Html.Partial("GetUsers")` you just render the PartialView and pass the View's Model to it, not `List<UserProfile>`.

Comment: thank you @Zabavsky I understand my problem. I switched to Action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetUsers` action doesn't seem to ever be called when you use `Html.Partial`. Maybe you wanted to use a child action:

```
@Html.Action("GetUsers")
```

Checkout the [`following article`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)  to better understand the difference between `Html.Partial` and `Html.Action`.

Also generating a dropdown list using a `foreach` loop instead of using the `Html.DropDownList` helper seems quite inappropriate. Maybe you wanted to use this helper, didn't you:

```
@model List<...UserProfile>
@Html.DropDown(
    "Meeting.SetToUser", 
    new SelectList(
        Model.Select(x => new 
        { 
            UserId = x.UserId, 
            FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName) }
        ),
        "UserId", 
        "FullName"
   )
)
```

I would also very strongly recommend you using view models instead of passing your domain models to the views.

Comment: Thank You Darin! I changed the Html.Partial to Html.Action and it works. I will read the article you provided. I appriciate your notes and will take them into account. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See closely GetUsers() action, You are passing model of type List to partial view where as partial view accepts type List<...UserProfile>.

The resolutions is to send a proper type what partial view is accepting.